# Problem of putting large-sized photos into a small ImageView without decreasing app speed or crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I got a problem when I wanted to put  my large-sized photos from my storage into  small imageViews. I´m wondering how to put these kind of photos inside a small imageViews  without decreasing app speed or crashing.
I have a RecyclerView that shows some pictures from storage in a list. Here is my recycler adapter code.
Thanks for your help.

```
class Adapter(files: ArrayList<File>):RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.myViewHolder>() {

    val files: ArrayList<File> = files

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): myViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_complex_note_view , parent , false)
        return myViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return files.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: myViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(files.get(position))
    }


    class myViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
            lateinit var imageView: ImageView

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.complex_note_view_item_imageview)
        }

        fun bind(file: File) {           
            imageView.setImageURI(file.toUri())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is using this code:

```
Glide.with(imageView.context)
                        .load(imageFile)
                        .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
                        .into(imageView)
```

Glide class is faster and more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you using **[picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)** with resize methode ,it will avoid you the lack of speed and crashes

```
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: It Works. Thank you.